# Jenkins throwing java.lang.StackOverflowError -- Not just on unstash

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, stack-overflow

Update July 31, 2019
The error sometimes happens before the unstash call, but always on the same server. In an effort to see if the problem was caused by unstash working in a directory where it needed to overwrite files, I cleaned the directory -- but the problem still happened. This time the output began (transcribed, any typos are my fault):

```
Running on my_agent in C:/Jenkins/workspace/script_name
. . .
Running in D:\mydir
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] bat
[mydir] Running batch script
D:\mydir> dir .
<output of dir command>
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:115)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:778)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
etc.
```

It did not reach the unstash call, but still got the same error.
= = = = =
Getting java.lang.StackOverflowError when unstashing in Jenkins on Windows 10; happens on one server but not another. Looks like unstash is getting infinite recursion.

- Same name for stash and unstash? -- yes; using same function to unstash on each.
- Reboot Jenkins master and slaves -- yes.
- Enough room on disk to unstash? -- yes.
- Web search on this error -- yes, but this problem not addressed.
- Has this worked in past? -- yes, unstash is working on one server but not another.
- Is target directory clean? -- yes.
- Tried at distinct times? -- yes.

```
def stash_my_stuff() {
    stash includes: '**', name: 'my_stash'
}
def unstash_my_stuff() {
    unstash 'my_stash'
}

// on one agent
dir("d:\\tmsc") { unstash_my_stuff() }

// later on a different agent
dir("d:\\tmsc") { unstash_my_stuff() }
```

```
13:23:33 Running in D:\tmsc
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] unstash
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] dir
13:24:01 Running in D:\tmsc
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:111)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:778)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
etc., etc., etc.
sometimes it also includes
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
```

Comment: I think your error stack contains typos. RiverMasrhaller.java?

Comment: The system I am running on does not connect to Internet, so I had to transcribe. Thanks for catching. Will correct.

Comment: I have a similar issue and I suspect it comes from parallel stages. Is that your case?

Comment: Did not come from parallel stages. I found a way to move the stage earlier, and did not have the problem. Still doesn't explain why it happened -- or how to stop it if I have to move the stage back where it was before.

Comment: Having similar (if not same) problem; stack overflow exception, lots of RiverMarshaller calls in stack. Also, happens in or just after a dir() call. Log output very similar: [Pipeline] dir
14:49:47  Running in ...
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.StackOverflowError

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar error and was able to ultimately resolve it by a couple things, one of which MarekR mentioned in his answer.

1. Update the jenkins.xml file to use a 64bit JRE
2. increase max heap size to 1024m for the JRE (in the jenkins.xml file)
3. increase the stack size to 4m in the jenkins.xml as well (-Xss4m)

Finally be sure to save the xml file and restart the jenkins service to pick up the new changes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Are you sure ALL are required? Looking at step 3, that would imply stack overflow cause infinite recursion, which in turn causes stack overflow. And I don't see how 64bit fit in unless heap is set to more than can be addressable by 32bit.

Comment: I did the first two and it's not failing anymore. Thanks.

Comment: The JRE max heap option is -Xmx. I did increase that to 1024m as suggested and that did fix the problem. ... but I don't recommend that solution, at least not in my situation (windows 10) and maybe not universally. Thing is, a JRE has a prebuilt limit that is probably different and probably tuned for each target environment. For Windows 10, it's 4096! I removed the option to use this default. And (of course) it works with that. I think the take away is to avoid using -Xmx (maybe all -X options) ... unless you know for sure the default is too small.

Answer (score 2):

I've encounter similar problem when using parallel stages.

I've found [bug report](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52966) about that. One of the [comment](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52966?focusedCommentId=371237&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-371237) (which is praised by next comment) recommends this:

> I encountered this issue too. I am using Jenkins on Windows which was
>   installed using the installer. After some digging, I realized that
>   this distribution of Jenkins comes packaged with a 32-bit version of
>   the JRE, and it is used by the Windows Service (which uses the
>   jenkins.xml file). This severely limits the amount of heap memory the
>   JVM can allocate. If you're facing this issue in the same situation,
>   modify jenkins.xml to use a different, 64-bit version of JRE and also
>   increase the max heap allocation (e.g. -Xmx1024m).

I didn't try that yet (I do not have proper access right to servers with Jenkins), but when I do it I will update the answer.

Comment: Still waiting to hear from Marek ;)

Comment: company started new Jenkins service where this issue doesn't exist and old system become obsolete. So can't verify that anymore.