# Jenkins job stops suddenly with "Stack Overflow" error

Tags: jenkins, runtime-error, stack-overflow, windows-server-2019

I have set up around 10 Jenkins jobs in a windows server and those job runs for roughly around 1h each to finish.
But in it one of the job which take roughly more than 1.5h, it frequently stops with ***Stack overflow*** error.

I tried increasing Heap size to 1024m as
[Jenkins throwing java.lang.StackOverflowError -- Not just on unstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57065665/jenkins-throwing-java-lang-stackoverflowerror-not-just-on-unstash) suggests.

I even reduced # of executors to 5 earlier it was at 10.

I even set up JavaMelody plugin in jenkins to get a basic report and to see if the heap size overloads.
I haven't checked the JavaMelody plugin status *while the jobs are running* but when I checked the status afterwards I do not see any overload issues in heap size.

I check the VM also it has more than enough space in it.

But still **either the job suddenly stops without any error or it shows this "Stack overflow" error**.
[image]

The job configuration is not complex either,
First I try to delete files in the workspace then by using a Test.exe (tool that was developed to run API testing) and passing parameters to it then passing that standard output to a log file and finally echoing that log back in to the jenkins console. (because I wanted to save the jenkins console output to a separate log file as well)
[image]

Are there any workarounds or solutions to resolve this?

Comment: Can you show us the pipeline script or job configuration?

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli I just updated, hope it's clear.